# Find phrases related to each other across multiple files

Tags: python

I have an issue trying to approach this issue, there is a folder with 6000 text files. What I need is to find phrases that repeat across all these files and include it in a report. The issue goes beyond a regular 

`grep -Hl <phrase> Folder/*.txt`

The issue is that I dont know the *phrase* to capture, is supposed to scan all documents and get 5 word segments and look around on the rest of the documents to find a match.

If there is a way that this can be achieved using python, I am all ears. I have think about **NTLK** or **Machine Learning** but would need more details about it.

Comment: Can you add an example?  Does ```5 word segments``` mean any five-word-grouping in a document?

Comment: Are you looking to first find a good candidate string to use to cluster the files?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [n-gram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) methodology. You can parse for "five-gram" segments within the files.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13424002/3761160) is a good example of how to use n-grams to find patterns in text. You would need to decide on a way to search through all of the text files. If they are small enough, you could combine them, or read them into a string, and parse from there.

[Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17547860/3761160) way to use n-grams.