# Generate ngram (bigram or trigram) in Keras / Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I want to generate generate *n-grams* from a sequence of tokens:

```
bigram:: "1 3 4 5" --> { (1,3), (3,4), (4,5) }
```

After searching I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30609050/1462770) thread that used:

```
def find_ngrams(input_list, n):
  return zip(*[input_list[i:] for i in range(n)])
```

If I use this piece of code during my training time I think it kills the performance. So I looking for a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to generate **bigram** in string format:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

sentence = ['this is example sentence']
x = tf.string_split(sentence).values[:-1] + ' ' + tf.string_split(sentence).values[1:]

# tf.Tensor([b'this is' b'is example' b'example sentence'], shape=(3,), dtype=string)
```

---

You can also use [`tensorflow-transform`](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/master/docs/api_docs/python/tft/ngrams.md) to generate ngrams.

```
import tensorflow_transform as tft

tft.ngrams(tensor, (1,2), " ")
```

**Note**: tensorflow-transform only supports python 2 until 22 January 2019.

Comment: The added bonus w/ these tf-transform ops is that they are driven by core graph ops, so they work outside of python! At least w/ my small experiment w/ `ngrams`...